# Airmeasure chart lines with Rails Charts / Chartkick/ Chart.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I would like to create multiple chart lines with [Rails Charts](https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts?tab=readme-ov-file#line-chart)

I have tried for some time and no succeeded.

I want to create something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn2Ma.png)

Each color line should represent **room_id** column from **airmeasures** table.

The x should take data from **timestamps** column, and the y line should take data from **measure_float** column.

I can also provide a link from my github if needed.
Or can be created with Chartkick / chart.js or any other(I have tried with those also)

Here is a [link](https://github.com/dFanTomb/pando2/blob/master/db/csv/20211101_B3D54FD00007B2.csv) from one csv file.

I have imported data from csv files to **seeds.rb** file.

```
require 'csv'

def import_csv(file_name)
  file_path = "db/csv/#{file_name}.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true) do |row|
    Airmeasure.create!(row.to_h)
  end
end

import_csv('20211101_B3D54FD00007B2')
import_csv('20211101_B3D54FD000088A')
import_csv('20211101_B3D54FD000088F')
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_11_23_221627) do
  create_table "airmeasures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "timestamps"
    t.string "measure_type"
    t.integer "measure_float"
    t.string "brand"
    t.string "serial_number"
    t.integer "establishment_id"
    t.string "establishment_name"
    t.string "establishment_city"
    t.string "establishment_postcode"
    t.string "establishment_address"
    t.float "establishment_latitude"
    t.float "establishment_longitude"
    t.integer "room_id"
    t.string "room_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <%= line_chart Airmeasure.order(timestamps: :asc).pluck(:timestamps, :measure_float) %>
    </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @airmeasures = Airmeasure.select("timestamps", "measure_type", "measure_float", "room_name")
  end
end
```